# Opening ajax modal popup using javascript?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, how to open Ajax modal popup extender using javascript. I mean, when user click on button the ajax modul popu has to display using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/ASPModalInAction.aspx

```
function ShowPopup() {
    $find('modalpopup').show();
    //$get('Button1').click();
}
```